# Spring REST Form Data PUT method

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have given below my spring controller and .xml file congif info .

```
class TestingController
{

    @RequestMapping(value="/addinfo",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void addInfo(@RequestBody Userinfo user){
}
```

context

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
<property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
<property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </map>
 </property>
```

This is working fine as i am expecting for the JSON and XML Request using REST Client.
for example : {"user":"test","cval":"12","mval":"12} JSON working fine .

when i try to pass the data like  user=test&cval=12&mval=12 using in request body using REST client  with header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
I am getting 415 error message.

My Requirement is 
SPring RESTfull Webservice need to handle the below Content-Type

1.application/json
2.application/xml
3.application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Regards
Vasanth D

Comment: You can't use `@RequestBody` with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Instead use `ModelAttribute`. You can declare multiple methods with different `@RequestMapping` restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Please share some sample code. so do i need two method in my controller to handle the different type of content-type ? Please clarifiy me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, with a `consumes` attribute in the `@RequestMapping` annotation. Alternatively, you could write and register your own `HttpMessageConverter` and continue using `@RequestBody`.

Comment: so my xxx.spring.xml file contains  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver for (application/json) JSON and (application/xml)XML  and HttpMessageConverter for  form-data "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is this right ?