# Spring REST to handle all Content-Type message

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Can you please suggest me how to write the Spring REST webservice which is handle the different kind of "ContentType" messages?

```
1.application/json 
2.application/xml 
3.application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

with the help of org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver API ?

Regards
Vasanth D

Comment: by default they handle everything. What exactly do you need? ti differentiate methods based on content type?

Comment: please refer the below link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554169/spring-rest-form-data-put-method

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a Pizza object, you might do it like this.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "pizzas")
public class PizzaController {

    private final PizzaService service;

    @Autowired
    public PizzaController(final PizzaService pizzaService) {
        this.service = pizzaService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE
            }
    )
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Pizza create(@RequestBody Pizza pizza) {
        return service.create(pizza); 
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.PUT,
            consumes = {
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE
            }
    )
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public Pizza update(@RequestBody Pizza pizza) {
        return service.update(pizza); 
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            consumes = {
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE
            }
    )
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public Pizza read(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        return service.get(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
            consumes = {
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE
            }
    )
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public Pizza delete(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        return service.delete(id);
    }
}
```

If you are using Spring 4 you can remove all the `@ResponseBody` annotations and replace `@Controller` with `@RestController`.

Comment: Thanks Jax for your time . I have added the same based on your input ,now i am getting the Message 404 method not found using SOAP UI ? Please share your valuable Suggestion .. Do i need to add anything in ContentNegotiatingViewResolver properties in .xml file

Comment: Hi Jax , I am getting the same .. while  try to send post request data content type is "application/form-urlencoded".. please help me

Comment: Post you XML configuration file.